# How to split big pandas df into multiple ones using for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following problem. I have a big dataframe `data`. I would like to split it into n small dataframes with a suffix `_n`. I tried:

```py
for suffix in range(0, 20):
    rows = len(data) // 20
    data + f"_{suffix}" = data[suffix*rows : (suffix+1)*rows]
```

But I got an error `Cannot assign to operator`. How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take df slice in range `[i,i+n)`, where `n` is the number of rows you want in the smaller dataframe, and i is the start index for each of the small dataframes, then you can create a dictionary using dictionary comprehension.

```py
n=5   # Max number of rows per dataframe
res={f'df_{i/n:.0f}':df.iloc[i:i + n, :] for i in range(0, df.shape[0], n)}
```

***PS:** replace `df` with the variable name for your dataframe.*